# What is the best way to scale down ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have more than one `Fragment` in `Viewpager` ,on long press I want to scale down the `Viewpager` in the middle of screen as shown in below image. I want to show All fragments in `Viewpager` like android OS on Home screen. I am doing this by using library,

```
compile 'com.pixplicity.multiviewpager:library:1.0'
```

Here is xml file,

```
<com.pixplicity.multiviewpager.MultiViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bott_sidemenu"
    app:matchChildWidth="@+id/vg" />
```

Here is child layout,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/vg"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_page"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/im_pixplicity"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But all item size does not scale down inside the `Viewpager` `Fragment`. Is there a way to so way? Suggestion will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: can you upload the code where you resize your fragment?

Comment: child layout is the resized Fragment android:layout_width="200dp"